# Initializing a AS 3.0 vector with type array - Vector.<Array>? (plus C++ equivelant)

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, porting

I have a quick question for you all. I'm trying to convert over some ActionScript code to C++ and am having a difficult time with this one line:

```
private var edges:Vector.<Array>
```

What is this exactly? Is this essentially a multidimensional vector then? Or is this simply declaring the vector as a container? I understand from researching that vectors, like C++ vectors, have to be declared with a type. However, in C++ I can't just put down Array, I have to use another vector (probably) so it looks like:

```
vector<vector<T> example;
```

or possibly even

```
vector<int[]> example;
```

I don't expect you guys to know the C++ equivalent because I'm primarily posting this with AS tags, but if you could confirm my understand of the AS half, that would be great. I did some googling but didn't find any cases where someone used Array as it's type.

Comment: What's the nature of this application you're trying to port from AS 3.0 to C++?

Comment: A* Pathfinding code. There is an array of nodes, and then there is another array that, I think, is filled with another array of numbers (an index), of which edges that node touches. This is what I'm porting over: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/artificial-intelligence-series-part-1-path-finding/

Comment: you can fill your vector with a vector (instead of an Array) : var vector : Vector.<Vector.<Number>>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mike Chambers (adobe evangelist) :

"Essentially, the Vector class is a typed Array, and in addition to ensuring your collection is type safe, can also provide (sometimes significant) performance improvements over using an Array."

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/19/using-vectors-in-actionscript-3-and-flash-player-10/

Essentially the vector in C++ is based on the same principles. As far as porting a vector of Arrays in AS3 to C++, well that's not a conversion that is clear cut in principle, as you could have a collection (array) of various types in C++, such as a char array. However, it appears you've got the idea, as you've pretty much posted examples of both avenues in your question.

I would post some code but I think you've got it exactly. Weather you use a vector within a vector or you declare a specifically typed collection I think comes down to a matter of what works best for you specific project.

Also you might be interested in:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/09/24/actioscript-3-vector-array-performance-comparison/

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the information I needed. Well done. =]